# Click on Dock should switch to full screen app, but this is broken. How to fix?

Tags: macos, dock, spaces, mission-control

Suppose I have a full screen app. I am on a Desktop space. I click on the full screen app's Dock icon, but nothing happens. I would expect the system to switch to that full screen app.

I vaguely remember turning this off via some defaults mockery a month ago. Now, setting `workspaces-auto-swoosh` to YES does not help. 'When switching to an application, switch to a Space...' option in Mission Control preferences is turned off but also does not help.

This works on a test account by default on same machine.

Additionally, in the ideal case, it would *only* switch when I explicitly click on Dock icon, the default behaviour to automatically switch every time an app has some popup dialog to display is also very annoying. I don't know if this is possible.

I am using OS X Yosemite.

Thank You!

Comment: I have that happen after some time up. It happens seemingly randomly for me and so far a reboot is my solution :(

Comment: try this in Terminal instead of rebooting... `killall -9 Dock`